# How to call on-premise REST API without OpenAPI Specification using Cloud SDK Java

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have one use case to call on-premise REST API via Cloud Connector. It is a custom API in SAP R/3 system. I checked with API developer and unfortunately they have no OpenAPI specification for it. Thus, I could not use OpenAPI generator to generate library.

Is there any other way to call on-premise REST API in such scenario like native call with connectivity service? We might have some more use cases with the same situation in future.

Is it possible to provide a generic REST client similar to OData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use-case you could leverage our `HttpClientAccessor` to instantiate a `HttpClient`.

```java
HttpDestination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("my-destination").asHttp();
HttpClient client = HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(destination);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(your-http-request-here);
```

You can read more details [here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/sdk-connectivity-http-client)